# Adding none to combobox

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to use the below example to add a value to combobox dynamically, but I'm running into errors.

[Option to select none in picklist fields lightning-combobox - LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273846/option-to-select-none-in-picklist-fields-lightning-combobox-lwc)

```
      <lightning-combobox
                                value={PicklistValues }
                                options={PicklistValues }
                                placeholder="Select an Option"
                                label="Name"
                                onchange={handleChange}>
                        </lightning-combobox>

@track PicklistValues;
      @wire(getPicklistValues, {
                recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
                fieldApiName : ACCOUNT_FIELD})
                getpicklistValues(result) {
                    if (result.data) {
                        this.PicklistValues = [ { label: 'None', value: 'None', selected: true }, ...result.data.values ];
                      } else if (result.error) {
                        console.log(result.error);
                    }
                }
```

I'm running into an error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'aChildren' of
>   undefined

Can someone suggest me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is `aChildren` comming from?

Comment: `PicklistValues` and `picklistValues` are not the same thing. You can't use `picklistValues` for both options and `value`.

Comment: @glls it is some where in the aura.js file                                                              Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'aChildren' of undefined
    at En (aura_prod.js:4)
    at Object.update (aura_prod.js:4)
    at dn (aura_prod.js:4)
    at fn (aura_prod.js:4)
    at aura_prod.js:4
    at Ir (aura_prod.js:4)
    at kn (aura_prod.js:4)
    at Object.update (aura_prod.js:4)
    at dn (aura_prod.js:4)
    at fn (aura_prod.js:4)

Comment: It seems to happening when I'm dispatching a event from the connectedcallback

Answer (score 1):

```
<lightning-combobox
        value={picklistValues}
        options={picklistValues}
        placeholder="Select an Option"
        label="Name"
        onchange={handleChange}>
</lightning-combobox>
```

**value={picklistValues}**

**options={picklistValues}**

have equals {picklistValues}. **value** - need to be **"None"** for example

Comment: I have updated my question, I still face the same issue.